# Firefox 33 doesn't see Java Plugin

Tags: firefox, browser, java, plugins

I am trying to enable Java (not JavaScript) in my Firefox v. 33 so that I can use applets within the browser.  Currently, I just get a dark gray box across the whole screen when I try to load an applet, without any error message or prompt to install plugin.

As per [these instructions](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/use-java-plugin-to-view-interactive-content), I tried going into the Firefox plugin page to activate it, however, it wasn't there listed.  I do have Java 7 installed and it is in the path:

```
>java -version
java version "1.7.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)
```

What do I need to do to get Firefox to see my Java installation and recognize it as a plugin so that I can enable it and view applets inside the browser?

Answer (score 1):

From the the [page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/use-java-plugin-to-view-interactive-content) you linked to in your question:

> Make sure the 32-bit version of Java is installed
>
> On 64-bit Windows, if you only have the 64-bit version of Java
>   installed, the Java plugin will not be available.
>
> **Current Firefox releases are 32-bit browsers and you will need to
>   install the 32-bit version of Java.**

Comment: I do need 64 bit java for my development work.  can i have a separate 32 bit java installation that is used for Firefox only?

Comment: You can do any development work with the 32 bit version of Java ... the 64 bit version is not necessary ...

Comment: i had to change it to 64 bit because i was having some problems in my IDE.  do you know if it's possible to have a java install that is dedicated to Firefox and is not in the path, e.g. can i go into the Registry and change where FF is getting Java from?

Comment: Alternatively you can use the 64 bit JDK and the 32 bit JRE. Just be sure to run the Java control panel and select the 32 bit JRE to use with Firefox.

Comment: Another alternative could be to use a 64 bit Waterfox ...