# Configure Firefox to use non-default Java installation

Tags: firefox, java, plugins

I am using a 64-bit Java 7 installation on Windows 7 64-bit.  As per [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/840298/firefox-33-doesnt-see-java-plugin), I was having trouble enabling Java applets to run inside Firefox just to find out that the 32-bit Firefox does not like 64-bit java.  I would like to keep my 64-bit java as my default installation, as I need it for my development work and my IDE did not like 32-bit, and have a separate 32-bit installation just for Firefox.

How can I change which Java installation Firefox is using so that it does not automatically pick up the one from the path?

Comment: The reason you cannot use the 64-bit installation of Java is because Firefox is a 32-bit process.  As for how it detects the path that is handled through the Java Control Panel applet.  You can also look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950720/how-can-i-test-java-applet-with-different-java-versions-in-firefox)

Comment: Your question is already answered in the "thread" you reference - "run the Java control panel and select the 32 bit JRE to use with Firefox."